# OpenCV - black screen instead of camera on Android

Tags: android, opencv

I used OpenCV3.4.0 and I implemented CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2.

But it showed me a black screen instead of camera.

This is my code.

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    matInput.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    matInput = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(matInput, matInput, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    return matInput;
```